# Como ler arquivo passando parte do nome em Java

Tags: java, regex, arquivo

**Exemplo.:**

O nome do meu arquivo seria `001nome.txt`, esse arquivo terá uma varia ação no nome dependendo da entidade, ou seja uma hora ele pode ser `001nome.txt` em outra hora pode ser `999nome.txt`.

**Dúvida.:**

Como posso passar para o Java abrir esse arquivo independente dessa variação no nome?

**Observação:** No `php` faço assim `*nome.txt` ai ele me retorna o arquivo que tem o final `nome.txt` independente do inicio do seu nome.

Answer (score 5):

## Usando a API do Java

Crie um objeto `File` apontando para o diretório e itere sobre os arquivos verifica se os mesmos possuem o padrão desejado.

A implementação da iteração pode ser feita com o método [`File.listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29), cujo parâmetro é um filtro (implementação de [`FileFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html)) e o retorno é um array de arquivos (`File[]`).

Para verificar o padrão no nome do arquivo, você pode usar uma expressão regular e o método [`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) da classe `String`.

Veja um exemplo:

```java
File pasta = new File(".");
File[] arquivos = pasta.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file, String nome) {
        return nome.matches("\\d+nome.txt");
    }
});
for (File file : arquivos) {
    System.out.println(file.getName());
}
```

## Usando Apache Commons IO

Porém, se você pode usar uma biblioteca como o [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io), é possível simplificar usando o `RegexFileFilter` ou o `WildcardFileFilter`. Veja os exemplos:

```java
File[] arquivos = pasta.listFiles(new RegexFileFilter(""\\d+nome.txt""));
```

Ou:

```java
File[] arquivos = pasta.listFiles(new WildcardFileFilter("*nome.txt"));
```

## Usando Google Guava

Outro exemplo com [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```java
File pasta = new File(".");
Iterable<File> iterable = Files
        .fileTreeTraverser()
        .breadthFirstTraversal(pasta)
        .filter(new Predicate<File>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(File input) {
                return input.getName().matches("\\d+nome.txt");
            }
        });
for (File f : iterable) {
    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Embora esse seja bastante verboso, ele permite iterar em subdiretórios também.

Answer (score 2):

Esse método resolveu um problema semelhante que tive.

```
FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {  
    public boolean accept(File file) {  
        return file.getName().endsWith("name.txt");  
    }  
};

File dir = new File("/caminho/do/seu/diretorio");  
File[] files = dir.listFiles(filter);
```

O `.endsWith("name.txt");` pode resolver parte do seu problema, já que ele pega todos os arquivos que terminam com a String especificada.

Answer (score 1):

Utile uma expressão próximo desta. Esta expressão permite algo como 20140512_0000_xxxxxxxxxx.xml.gz  sendo yyyymmdd_hhmm_cliente.xml.gz

Passe esta expressão para o `getFilter()` depois utilize o `getListFiles()`

Esta classe RegexFileFilter é o projeto **apache commons io**

```
"^[\\d]{8}_[\\d]{4}_[\\w]+\\.xml\\.gz$"

 private List<File> getListFiles() {
    List<File> list = Arrays.asList(this.sourceDirectory.listFiles(getFilter()));
    Collections.sort(list);
    return list;
  }    

  private FileFilter getFilter() {
    return new RegexFileFilter(FILE_FILTER);
  }
```

Comment: A classe [`FileFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) é do Java, porém a `RegexFileFilter` realmente é do Commons IO.

Comment: Aqui no projeto que estou preferimos utilizar o Commons IO por esta facilidade e outras também... utilizamos muito o StrinUtils, EnumUtils, ToStringUtils... e por ae vai... hehehehe