# Localizar e abrir arquivo .txt, acrescentar informações e salvar em java

Tags: java

Estou com um projetinho de uma sistema para clinicas onde o recepcionista faz o cadastro do paciente colocando suas informações pessoais e salvando num arquivo txt. Ai quando o medico receber o paciente ele ira procurar o nome do arquivo do paciente através de uma lista, logo, abrir o txt e somente acrescentar as informações referentes ao exame e logo em seguida salvar. Abaixo esta meu código do cadastro do paciente, alguém pode me ajudar a acrescentar essa função?

Cadastrar o paciente na recepção:

```
    public class Cadastrar {

    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nomeArq="Relatorio.pdf";
    String nome;
    String ender;
    String email;
    String tel;
    String bairro;
    String numero;
    String exame;

    public void Inserir(){
    File arquivo; 
    System.out.printf("Nome completo do paciente: ");
    nome = ler.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Endereço: ");
    ender = ler.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Bairro: ");
    bairro = ler.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Número: ");
    numero = ler.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Telefone: ");
    tel = ler.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("E-mail: ");
    email = ler.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Exame: ");
    exame = ler.nextLine();

    nomeArq = nome +".txt";

    try
    {
      Formatter saida = new Formatter(nomeArq);
      saida.format("          --- Ficha cadastral de pacientes ---");
      saida.format("\n Nome do paciente: "+nome+"\n");
      saida.format("\n Endereço: "+ender+"\n");
      saida.format("\n Bairro: "+bairro+"\n");
      saida.format("\n Numero: "+numero+"\n");
      saida.format("\n Email: "+email+"\n");
      saida.format("\n Telefone: "+tel+"\n");
      saida.format("\n Exame: "+exame+"\n");
      saida.close();
        System.out.println("Arquivo '"+nomeArq+"' Salvo com sucesso!");
    }
    //mostrando erro em caso se nao for possivel gerar arquivo
    catch(Exception erro){
      System.out.println("Arquivo nao pode ser gerado!");
    }
    }
}
```

cadastrar exame do paciente:

```
private void Sangue() {

Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
String nomeArq="Exame de sangue.pdf";
int i;
String Hemácias;
String Hemoglobina;
String Hematócritos;
String HGM;
String Volume;
String Hemog;
String Mielócitos;
String Bastões;

File arquivo; 
System.out.printf("Hemácias: ");
Hemácias = ler.next();
System.out.printf("Hemoglobina: ");
Hemoglobina = ler.next();
System.out.printf("Hematócritos: ");
Hematócritos = ler.next();
System.out.printf("H.G.M: ");
HGM = ler.next();
System.out.printf("Volume corporal médio: ");
Volume = ler.next();
System.out.printf("Conc. Hemog. Corp. Média: ");
Hemog = ler.next();
System.out.printf("Mielócitos");
Mielócitos = ler.next();
System.out.printf("Bastões");
Bastões = ler.next();


try
{
  Formatter saida = new Formatter(nomeArq);
  saida.format("          --- Ficha cadastral de pacientes ---");
  saida.format('\n'+"Nome do paciente: "+Hemácias);
  saida.format('\n'+"Endereço: "+Hemoglobina);
  saida.format('\n'+"Bairro: "+Hematócritos);
  saida.format('\n'+"Numero: "+HGM);
  saida.format('\n'+"Email: "+Volume);
  saida.format('\n'+"Telefone: "+Hemog);
  saida.format('\n'+"Exame: "+Mielócitos);
  saida.format('\n'+"Exame: "+Bastões);
  saida.close();
    System.out.println("Arquivo '"+nomeArq+"' Salvo com sucesso!");
}
//mostrando erro em caso se nao for possivel gerar arquivo
catch(Exception erro){
  System.out.println("Arquivo nao pode ser gerado!");
}

}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como ler dados de arquivos txt usando Java?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74972/como-ler-dados-de-arquivos-txt-usando-java)

Comment: Nesse post eh somente de leitura, eu quero ler e adicionar mais conteudo ao arquivo. E pra isso tambem será necessario primeiro fazer uma busca pra localizar o arquivo pelo nome do paciente.

Comment: A segunda resposta de la ensina tanto ler quanto escrever, por isso que setei como duplicata.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como posso navegar e editar um arquivo txt em Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/128174/28595) e [Como ler arquivo passando parte do nome em Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7842/28595)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Java 8, você pode acrescentar conteúdo a um arquivo facilmente usando [`Files.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-):

```
Files.write(path, bytes, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

Há também [outra versão](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) onde você pode passar uma coleção de Strings, tal como um `List<String>`.

Um exemplo bem simples:

```
//cria um arquivo temporário qualquer
Path arquivo = Files.createTempFile("pre", ".tmp");

//"prepara" dois conteúdos, incluindo as quebras de linha se precisar
String content1 = "Content1\n";
String content2 = "Content2\n";

//grava o primeiro conteúdo
Files.write(arquivo, content1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

//acrescenta o segundo conteúdo
Files.write(arquivo, content2.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

//recupera o conteúdo do arquivo e imprime
String finalContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(arquivo), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(finalContent);
```